# Fedora 19 zfsonlinux - how to configure cifs share?

Tags: fedora, zfs, cifs, smb

Fedora 19 with current version of zfsonlinux / smb version 4.0.9.  When I try to

```
zfs set sharesmb=on
```

I receive

```
smb add share failed
```

Any ideas?  Is this supposed to work yet or still in development?

Comment: It seems that zfsonlinux already implemented wiring samba shares on zfs datasets - https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/1182 . Maybe you missed the path that will be shared: `zfs set sharesmb=on zfspool/srv/example` - http://zfsonlinux.org/faq.html#HowDoISetupShares.  I could be selinux annoying you too.

Answer (score 7):

By default the `USERSHARE` feature of samba is disabled in Fedora. Enabling it is not enough as libshare in the ZFSOnLinux requires a specific `usershare path` to be set.

To get it working set the following in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[global]
    usershare path = /var/lib/samba/usershares
    usershare max shares = 100
    usershare allow guests = yes
    usershare owner only = no
```

Then make the `/var/lib/samba/usershares` directory as root:

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/samba/usershares
```

After restarting `smb` and `nmb` `zfs set sharesmb=on <filesystem>` will work.